# What is Client & Server side DataTable processing?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have tried but failed in researching on Google and here to get a basic, but good understanding about the meaning of  Client and Server side jQuery dataTable processing. I know the Client is usually the web browser and it interacts with the user, and the server is the http server, but not more than that. If someone can please help in giving a brief description on both aspects of data processing? If it is with examples, it would be awesome. And if not, still great.

```
<table id="datatable" class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Budget)
        ........
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
    ...........

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datatable').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

So, is the script code above all I need to do for Client side processing?

Comment: With DataTables think of server side processing as having multiple calls to your server side database. An example of this would be paging. Page one of 100 records would be one call while page two of the next 100 would be another.

Comment: Client side is often when the whole Dataset is given to the client in the first request. Paging, and searching are all done on the client side with no other calls to the server. Large data sets can often be too much for a browsers so server side processing in those situations is often a requirement for performance

Comment: So, is the script code which I added above in my post all I need to do for Client side dataTable processing?

Comment: Yes thats the most basic initialisation possible for DataTables. Just make sure you have links to the Datatables.min.js javascript file and its stylesheet. So long as there is data in the table you should have all the basic paging, filter and order functionality show in this table here: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please read official documentation regarding [processing modes](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Processing-modes).

- **Client-side processing** - the full data set is loaded up-front and data processing (ordering, filtering, pagination) is done in the browser.

  See [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) of data table using client-side processing mode.
- **Server-side processing** - an Ajax request is made for every table redraw, with only the data required for each display returned. The data processing (ordering, filtering, pagination) is performed on the server.

  See [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) of data table using server-side processing mode.

Comment: Which one is preferrable?

Comment: @TuralAsgar, client-side processing mode is simple to implement than server-side processing mode. If your data set is large, with client-side processing mode there would be a delay before data is retrieved and every time you search or sort. In this case use server-side processing instead.

Answer (score 0):

In Simple Words,

**Client-Side** - All data is sent to the browser once by the server. After that, all is handled by JS in frontend like pagination, sorting, etc.

**Server-Side** - Ajax call is made to each request and only that particular data is sent. For e.g show 10 records, here an AJAX call is made to fetch these 10 records hence only these records are sent by a server instead of full data. The same goes to pagination, search, filter, etc.

- For better performance, Server-Side data is the best solution(For huge
  data).
- Client-Side is best for less data